# I updated Chrome through brew cask and getting suspicious behavior

Tags: google-chrome, browser, malware, malware-removal, malware-detection

I have updated my Google Chrome to version 59.0.3071.115 by using:
 
`brew cask reinstall google-chrome`
and now when I start chrome, it opens two tabs with these URLs:
 
`http://www.prosoftwarepc.com/adblock-plus/`
and
`http://ww1.prodownnet.info/`
which both seem suspicious to me.

I am worried something is wrong. For now, I deleted this install and downloaded the latest chrome from [google's chrome download page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop) instead.

How can I make sure everything is OK?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reach the websites and firefox told me they are fake/suspicious.
I think the best option is to remove and reinstall chrome.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable`

and

`rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome`

just to be sure.

You should also check if there is any plugins/addons that look suspicious and remove them if so.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually on macOS (hence the `brew` usage, but should have mentioned Mac explicitly). I already reinstalled Chrome, but I had a look in the extensions and apparently there was a fake Adblock Plus version that didn't exist in the Chrome webstore anymore. I removed that immediately, but I'm actually troubled as to how much harm this could have done? Is there any way of making sure?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were on linux(brew is also on linux). I don't know much about Mac but there is a cool tool that might get you rid of potential malwares : https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/